# How to get controller and his action name with router prefix Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in Ruby on Rails and i am using Ruby Version 1.9.3 and Rails version 4.0.2.

My query is:

How to get controller and his action name with router prefix in application controller?

See Below my code:-

**See Router**

```
root :to=>"home#index"
get "admin/" => "admin/users#index"
get "admin/sign_in" => "admin/users#sign_in"
get "sign_in" => "admin/users#sign_in"
```

**See my application controlle**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:alert] = "Access denied. You are not authorized to access the requested page."
    redirect_to root_path and return
  end

  before_filter :current_user, :get_model

  def current_user

    # Note: we want to use "find_by_id" because it's OK to return a nil.
    # If we were to use User.find, it would throw an exception if the user can't be found.
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_authentication_token(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token] && @current_user.nil?
    @current_user

  end

  def authenticate_user
    @mydata = params
    if current_user.nil?
      flash[:error] = 'You must be signed in to view that page.'
      redirect_to :admin_sign_in
    end
  end
end
```

`def authenticate_user` method i have create in application controller.

I want

**if current_user.nil?** and router prefix is **admin Like localhost:3000/admin**

it will be redirect on admin sign in path

```
 redirect_to :admin_sign_in
```

Other then it will be redirect front end sign in part

```
 redirect_to :sign_in
```

Update my question

**My query is how to set condition according to controller and action name with namespace in authenticate_user method where redirect to page.**

Please help. How it is possible?

Comment: you're basically looking for the path of the url right? Like that's what 'admin' in localhost:3000/admin is. I think namespacing is the way to go, but if you really want to do this, `request.path` should work. Again, I don't think it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use namespaces in your routes.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing
especially chapter 2.6

```
2.6 Controller Namespaces and Routing
You may wish to organize groups of controllers under a namespace. Most commonly, you might group a number of administrative controllers under an Admin:: namespace. You would place these controllers under the app/controllers/admin directory, and you can group them together in your router:

namespace :admin do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Also call admin_sign_in_path or sign_in_path instead of symbols. to see all routes in you app use rake routes .

Comment: i have already set namespace in route. but my query is how to set condition according to controller and action name with namespace in authenticate_user method where redirect to page.

Comment: 1) create separate application controller for admin namespace and inherit all controllers in admin namespace from this controller. Then just overwrite method "authenticate user" in this controller.

Comment: sample can be found here: https://github.com/offtop/so-20998892/tree/master/app/controllers Take a view on application_controller and admin/application_controller